# Fixing autocorrelation error on sum of averages

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, error-analysis

I'm running a Monte Carlo simulation with the Metropolis algorithm to compute a quantity of the form $$U\propto \langle y^2\rangle_P+\langle\Delta y^2\rangle_P $$ where $P$ is the distribution at equilibrium of the simulation. In particular, the algorithm returns a number of discretized Feynman paths distributed according to the weight $P[y]=e^{-S[y]}$, where $S$ is the Euclidean action of the harmonic oscillator.

Since each iteration only slightly changes each point of the discrete paths, the data is autocorrelated (i.e., paths that are returned in succession are similar to each other). My question is: what method can I use to correctly compute the error on $U$ itself, either directly or given the errors on the two Monte Carlo averages?

Answer (score 0):

I'll formalise the problem a bit. I’m assuming that you have an infinite stationary, stochastic process representing your data points $(x_i)$ (you reached the equilibrium distribution). You want to compute the variance of the empirical mean (in the limit of large $N$):
$$
\bar x_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i
$$
Since you are only interested in the variance I will assume that the process has zero mean:
$$\langle x_i\rangle=0$$

This simplifies the correlation function $C_{ij}=\langle x_ix_j\rangle$ depends only on the relative distance $|i-j|$ so that you can write
$$
C_{ij}=C(|j-i|)
$$
with in particular $C(0)$ the common variance.
You just need to calculate:
$$
\langle \bar x_N^2\rangle = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^N\langle x_ix_j\rangle \\
=\frac{1}{N^2} \left(NC(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(N-n)C(n)\right) \\
\sim \frac{1}{N}\left(C(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}C(n)\right)
$$
under the assumption that the $C$ is summable, which is the case for Markov chains of finite states since it decays exponentially asymptotically. Your problem is reframed into estimating the RHS series:
$$
S = C(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}C(n)
$$

A first method is to estimate the to correlation function $C$ from the data. Typically do an exponential fit and calculate the series analytically from the fitted value of the ratio.

A second method is the bunching method analogous to a renormalisation group procedure. You map your original stochastic process $(x_i)$ to a new (stationary, zero mean) one $(x_i')$ by averaging two consecutive terms (coarse graining):
$$
x_i' = \frac{x_{2i-1}+x_{2i}}{2}
$$
This new process will have a different correlation function $C'$, given explicitly by:
$$
C'(0) = \frac{C(0)+C(1)}{2} \\
C'(n\geq 1) = \frac{C(2n)}{2}+\frac{C(2n+1)+C(2n-1)}{4}
$$
After coarse graining, the series $S$ is simply transformed into:
$$
S' = \frac{S}{2}
$$
(each odd term appears twice from two consecutive terms). The idea is that after many steps, the coarse graining concentrates the correlation function around zero, effectively rendering the process uncorrelated. This can be seen in the case of exponential decay as the transformation halves the decay time. You can therefore use the naive formula after many steps, without forgetting renormalising it appropriately (multiply by $2^k$ after $k$ steps).

In practice, when you have a finite number of data, you compute the naive variance assuming that they are uncorrelated. You then coarse grain, which effectively increases the naive variance until it converges to the true $S$. Note that since you are halving the amount of data at each step, the statistical error also increases, so the plateau effect may not be easily visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Obligatory question: since I'm programming in Python, are there any libraries where this stuff is implemented already?

Comment: Also: this method would allow me to compute the error on each average value, namely $\sigma_{y^2}$ and $\sigma_{\Delta y^2}$. What about their sum? Should I simply compute it with standard propagation of uncertainty, i.e. $$ \sigma_U=\sqrt{\sigma_{y^2}^2+\sigma_{\Delta y^2}^2+2\sigma_{y^2}\sigma_{\Delta y^2}}\quad ?$$

Comment: Not that I know of. But if you are already using a library, perhaps there is something already implemented.

Comment: In general it depends on on the correlation of the variables, so your formula may not be accurate enough. You can apply the method directly to the observable $y^2+\Delta y^2$ and you’ll get the variance of $U$ without any biases

Comment: Of course, thank you. How is this whole procedure related to the process of bootstrapping? That is, can you also compute the error on $U$ by block resampling from the data, with blocks of size $k$ chosen randomly and $k$ large enough to correct for autocorrelation?

Comment: I don’t know if there is a link. Bootstrapping is quite different since you are creating a new data in the simplest case using sampling with replacement.  Even with the bunching method, i am not generating new data, i’m just using the data available. Naturally, you could also implement bootstrapping techniques which work in general, but they will be more costly computationally since you don’t make any assumptions on the distribution of the data.

Comment: Forgive me, but I have just realized one issue with your answer. Your bunching method works nicely if the goal is computing the error on the mean $\langle y\rangle$ given the data $\{y_i\}$. But how do you adapt it to computing the error on $U$? Consider that in my case, each $y_i$ is a vector that must be averaged to find $y^2, \Delta y^2$ and only then you can compute $U$ as a Monte Carlo average. I'm not sure how to apply what you said to this specific situation.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand, but normally it does not change much. You just have a string of data $U_i=y_i^2+\Delta y_i^2$ on which you can apply the bunching method. Perhaps you might need to go into more detail what the variables represent and how they are simulated

Comment: This is how the algorithm works: once equilibrium is reached, every iteration $i=1,...,N$ gives a path of $n$ points $\text{path}=(y_1,...,y_n)$. The path itself is not stored, but only its average position squared $\langle y^2\rangle_{\text{path}}$ as well as $\langle \Delta y^2\rangle_{\text{path}}$, where $\Delta y=y_j-y_{j+1}$ (this is the same for all $j=1,...,n$). The quantity $U$ is then computed  for some $\eta$ as $$U=\frac{1}{2\eta}-\frac{1}{2\eta^2}\langle \Delta y\rangle_{MC}+\frac{1}{2}\langle y^2\rangle_{MC},$$ where the averages $MC$ is now taken on all N paths.

Comment: ok, then my previous comment still applies